# End of file Parse Error, Syntax error in Insert PHP Plugin used code

Tags: php, plugins, insert

I used a PHP code plugin called insert PHP in wordpress page. I have written a code which shows me a `syntax error` when run, what should I do?:

The error it gives is

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\mapletreefarm\wp-content\plugins\insert-php\insert_php.php(48) : eval()'d code on line 9"

```
[insert_php]
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
echo $_POST["name"];
echo "<br>";
echo $_POST["email"];
}
else 
{  
[/insert_php] 

<html>
<body>
<form action=" " method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"> <br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"> <br>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>  
[insert_php]
}
[/insert_php]
```

Comment: Please post the entire error you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is because [the php_insert plugin parses each php block as a stand-alone block of code](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/insert-php/trunk/insert_php.php).
So, your first block is a block of code that ends in `{`, which is impossible.

The only way I see to make this work is to put all code in a single php block and echo the html for the form.

```
[insert_php]
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    echo $_POST["name"];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $_POST["email"];
}
else 
{

    echo '<html>
        <body>
            <form method="post">
                Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br />
                E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br />
                <input type="submit" name="submit">
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>';
}
[/insert_php]
```

Comment: When i pasted the code ,it replies:

Comment: Oops! That page can’t be found.
It looks like nothing was found at this location. Maybe try a search?

Search for:

Comment: That's a 404 error and has nothing to do with this code. Are you sure you are using the correct url?

Comment: When i changed the code to make it echo the word "hello", it did worked. Hence there is something wrong with the first fourlines of the echo code:

Comment: IT WORKS, THANKS. i just changed the names of the form variables and echoed them and it works.

Comment: Glad I could help. :) If this answer solved the problem, consider marking it as the solution so other users might also find this.